# ASP.NET OIDC not redirecting after sign out

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I'm using OIDC with ASP.NET to connect to Amazon Cognito as an identity provider. At the moment it all works fine – on sign-out, I direct the user to the Cognito logout page, with a redirect set back to `/signout-oidc` on my app, which all works correctly.

However, `/signout-oidc` is a blank page, and at the moment I have to manually navigate back to `/` to continue using the site. How can I get ASP.NET to redirect to `/` after `/signout-oidc`?

Neither [`SignedOutCallbackPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.signedoutcallbackpath?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-openidconnect-openidconnectoptions-signedoutcallbackpath) nor [`SignedOutRedirectUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.signedoutredirecturi?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-openidconnect-openidconnectoptions-signedoutredirecturi) work when set to `/` in the OIDC options in `Startup.cs`.